# Call Method By Event width JS OOP (prototype)

Tags: javascript, oop

i hope anybody can help me =)

I try to keep the example simple:

```
function myClass(){
//some Code
}

myClass.prototype.func1 = function(){
//some Code
}

myClass.prototype.func2 = function(){
   document.getElementById("myEl").onclick = function(){
      this.func1 //does not work, this is only the Element...
   }
}
```

How does it works to call func1? I want to bind the onclick-event in func2.

Comment: This question is not really OOP related. It is a scope problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to keep a reference to the current object. As you already noticed, inside the event handler, `this` refers to the DOM element. You can do this with

```
var self = this;
```

Second, you have to actually *call* the function:

```
self.func1();
```

Complete example:

```
myClass.prototype.func2 = function(){
   var self = this;
   document.getElementById("myEl").onclick = function(){
      self.func1();
   };
}
```

---

In the newer browsers you can also use [`.bind()` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to explicitly define what `this` should refer to (see the MDN docs for a shim for other browsers):

```
document.getElementById("myEl").onclick = this.func1.bind(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside the `onclick` function, the `this` value is bound to the element being clicked. You need to keep a copy (a reference) to the `this` inside of func2:

```
myClass.prototype.func2 = function(){
    var self = this; //keep a reference to the this value
    document.getElementById("myEl").onclick = function(){
        self.func1();
    }
}
```